# How to locate an HTML file on localhost using Google Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a website using Wordpress on Localhost. I'm learning the structure of the webpage by editing the HTML and CSS using Google Developer Tools. I want to know which file I'm editing and where on the hard drive it is located.[image]

I have edited the height and width of an element inside the circle marked but when I try to save the file, it asks me for a location to save which I'm unaware of. One the left is the HTML code, how can I locate the file with that HTML code?

Comment: The changing you are doing on the dev tools are not applied to the website file you save, you have to open the file itself and make the changes there.

Comment: Browsers' Ctrl+S-save tools are as rudimentary as they've always been; they'll modify the HTML so the CSS and JavaScript files refer to a local folder, and are intended only for basic pages for personal use; it has little to do with web development. The server you're running won't tell the browser where the source files are (just as "google.com" won't tell you where the source files are on their server) so you may need to do some more introspection on the software you're using. (Apache Webserver? Tomcat? ASP.NET?)

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development to understand where the actual CSS and HTML template files are located. You'd likely be looking for style.css within your web servers document root for the site in question.

Comment: Instead of searching and editing the HTML file, I added some classes to the style.css file and edited the elements that way. The problem is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

> how can I locate the file with that HTML code?

You can’t – not really, not from within your browser, because your browser doesn’t see individual “files”, it only sees the complete HTML source code of the one resource it requested, that might have been composed of lots of different files, plus functions that generate HTML code dynamically – so that actual piece of HTML code might not even be written as such within a file.

You might be able to identify different sections of the HTML document though – and with a little knowledge of the template structure and output logic of WordPress, you should be able to find out what the relevant file to look in might most likely be.

Another thing I’d suggest, is that you get yourself an IDE that allows you to search across all files in the whole project folder – and than look for certain class names, IDs etc. on the HTML element in question or near/above it. If you search for those, you might get lucky as well. (Although a lot of times those classes/IDs might be output dynamically as well, so you won’t find them inside of a template file as such.)

Especially with little knowledge of WP template structures, it might take some trial and error to find the piece of code and file you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Developer Tools is not a code editor, so whilst you can try out different options I'm not aware that you can save it, and if you can, I wouldn't say it's a good idea.

Wordpress uses PHP, a language which HTML code is embedded with PHP code. For example the code `<a href='<?php echo(link1);?>'>Home</a>` has had the href attribute embedded with a PHP variable. If you want to find the HTML code, look at the PHP files in your Wordpress directory, index.php is the landing page code.

One thing to bear in mind is that not all the HTML code will be included in one PHP file, it is usually included from several files, and much of the content will be in the wp-content directory, keep an eye out for the PHP `include` or `require` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Google developer tool is just to check, once you are done with the editing, You have to copy your css code- and paste in your css file.

To get the css file look at the below image.

Hope your question got clarified!! [image]

Comment: Actually, my doubt was to edit the HTML file and not the CSS, but at the end I fixed the problem by adding classes to the style.css file.